# make a program run a number of times based on user input

Tags: c#, forms, recursion, textbox

I have a windows form program that I would like to 'run' a certain number of times based on a number that the user specifies.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and C#.

I have a program that has 16 picture boxes and randomly assigns pictures to 5 of these boxes. The person has to select the correct order of pictures. If they do, they are rewarded, if they choose wrong, they are punished by an annoying sound.

My first form has a TextBox that the user can specify the 'numberOfTrials'
I have a second form that takes the value of the TextBox and converts it into an int.

I want to have the main program on my second form run the number of times that the user specifies.

My program does work if I run it once, without using this variable.

I have tried using a for loop inside the method that starts the program, but this did not work. It just made all of the picture boxes white.

I then tried to use the for loop around the InitializeComponent() method but, again, this just made all of the picture boxes white.

My for loop uses the textbox variable as such:

```
for (int cycles = 0; cycles < numberOfTimesThrough; cycles++)
```

I create the numberOfTimesThrough variable by parsing the textbox variable.

Perhaps I am doing this wrong?

On the first form:

at the top of the class:

```
public static string trialNumberString;
```

inside a method that is called when a confirm button is pressed:

```
trialNumberString = tbTrialNumber.Text.ToString();
```

On the second form:

at the top of the class:

```
//Integer value for the string of trials
public static int numberOfTimesThrough;
bool canConvert = Int32.TryParse(Settings.trialNumberString, out numberOfTimesThrough);
```

Is this the correct way to get the string value of the textbox on the first form?
I am sure that adding a for loop *should* make the program repeat itself, so there must be something wrong with the way I am parsing the textbox string to an int.
The people using this program are not wanting to break it so the data entered into the textbox on the first form will always be between 1 and, say, 25. Do I still have to use a try catch around the string conversion?

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need to re-run the entire program just to show a form multiple times: instead, just instantiate multiple instances of the second form and show them in sequence.
- To safely parse text as a number, you can use int.TryParse()

Comment: I like your idea of showing multiple instances. To do this do I just write InitializeComponent() multiple times on the second form or do I call the second form multiple times from the first form?

Comment: @smokeAndMirrors I would create multiple instances of the second form from the first form

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of the textBox by accessing it's `Text` property and from there parse the string it returns to an int.

```
string s = textBox.Text;
int i = int.Parse(s);
```

Use whatever validation logic is necessary as well.

Comment: I did try this method but I received an error message that said "Cannot implicitly convert a string to an int" :-(

Comment: Actually, I didn't try using textBox.text I only used textBox.Text.toString() I will try it without the toString() tag.

Answer (score 0):

When application closes, static variables are deleted from memory too.  In order to save setting, you need to save it to separate file and then read that. Simple way of read/write settings is using build-in options of ApplicationSettings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a65txexh(v=vs.100).aspx